# 401 client error with Python Requests delete() method

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, teamcity, teamcity-rest-api

I am using Requests module with REST API. Attempted to delete TeamCity build configuration and caught into 401 client error. curl works, see below.

```
curl -u admin:password -X DELETE url
```

But not through Requests delete() method, see below.

```
requests.delete(url)
```

Example of url is https://teamcity_server/app/rest/buildTypes/build_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

401 status code means your request is unauthorized. In curl you give `user:password` but not in `requests.delete(url)`. You can pass authentication parameters to `requests` functions in this way:

```
request.delete(url, auth=('admin', 'password'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! However, using the previous approach (without auth) works for deleting parameter setting. Any thought would be appreciated.